Lebesgue measure of a singleton set
I am reading Measure Theory and Probability Theory by Athreya and Lahiri, and they make the following statement about the Lebesgue measure, $m(\cdot)$:

It follows from equation (3.1), that $\mu_F^*(\{x\}) = F(x+) - F(x-)$ and hence $=0$ if $F$ is continuous at $x$. Thus $m(\{x\}) \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to verify this for myself. For reference, I will include equation (3.1) below and other relevant identities from the book.

$$\mu_F^*(A) \equiv \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_F(A_n) : \{A_n\}_{n\geq1} \subset \mathcal{C} ,\, A \subset \bigcup_{n\geq1} A_n \right\} . \tag{3.1}$$


$$\mathcal{C} \equiv \Big\{ (a,b] : -\infty \leq a \leq b < \infty \Big\} \cup \Big\{ (a,\infty) : -\infty \leq a < \infty \Big\} . \tag{3.7}$$


Let $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be nondecreasing. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $F(x+) \equiv \lim_{y \downarrow x} F(y)$, and $F(x-) \equiv \lim_{y \uparrow x} F(y)$. Set $F(\infty) = \lim_{x \uparrow \infty} F(x)$ and $F(-\infty) = \lim_{x \downarrow -\infty} F(x)$. Define
\begin{align}
  \mu_F((a,b]) & = F(b+) - F(a+) ,
  \\
  \mu_F((a,\infty)) & = F(\infty) - F(a+) . \tag{3.8}
\end{align}


When $F(x) \equiv x ,\, x \in \mathbb{R}$, the measure $\mu_F^*$ is called the Lebesgue measure.

Here is my attempt.
Note that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $\epsilon>0$, $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon] \in \mathcal{C}$ and $\{x\} \subset (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$. By monotonicity of $\mu_F^*$, $$\mu_F^*(\{x\}) \leq \mu_F^*((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]).$$ By additivity of $\mu_F^*$, $$\mu_F^*((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]) = \mu_F^*((x-\epsilon,x]) + \mu_F^*((x,x+\epsilon]).$$ It was previously shown in the book that $\mu_F^*(A) = \mu_F(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{C}$. Therefore, $$\mu_F^*((x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]) = \mu_F((x-\epsilon,x]) + \mu_F((x,x+\epsilon]).$$ It follows from equation (3.8) that $$\mu_F((x-\epsilon,x]) + \mu_F((x,x+\epsilon]) = F((x+\epsilon)+) - F((x-\epsilon)+).$$ Hence, $$\mu_F^*(\{x\}) \leq F((x+\epsilon)+) - F((x-\epsilon)+).$$ Since this inequality holds for any $\epsilon>0$, I suspect that $$\mu_F^*(\{x\}) \leq F(x+) - F(x-).$$ Furthermore, I suspect that the opposite inequality ($\geq$) holds, too, so that we get $$\mu_F^*(\{x\}) = F(x+) - F(x-).$$ However, I have no idea how to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

You can show this directly by an epsilon-delta argument.
Using the definition of continuity at $x$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\vert F(y)-F(x)\vert \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. By definition of one sided limits there exists $x_1,x_2 $ such that  $x-\delta< x_1< x<x_2\leq x +\delta$, $F(x-)-F(x_1)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $F(x_2)-F(x+)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Choosing some $x_1<x_1'<x$ and putting these all together you get that
$$ \mu_F (\{ x \})\leq \mu_F \big( (x_1', x_2] \big) < \epsilon \quad \text{for all} \quad \epsilon>0. $$
Alternatively, you can use that if $E$ is a countable intersection of sets $\{ 
E_n \}\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ such that $E_{n+1}\subseteq E_n$ and $\mu_F^*( E_1  )<\infty$, then $\mu_F^*(E)= \lim_n \mu_F^*(E_n)$. Then you can just take $E_n=(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]$ and see that it implies the identity you wanted. But this uses a proposition about measures
